# Android Studio Failed after upgrade from 3.1.4 to 3.2.1

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk

Build of ics-openvpn failed after upgrading to the latest Android studio 3.2.1
it was working fine with 3.1.4
and there were no issues when it was on previous version of android 3.2.1
Please help me fix this issue to build this project file on android studio again

Android studio version 3.2.1
Windows 7 x64

The following is the output log on debug window when building

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\Woshi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {--build C:\Users\Woshi\Downloads\nw\ics-openvpn\main\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\noovpn3Debug\x86 --target ovpn3}
[1/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1.c.o
[2/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1_99.c.o
[3/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1a.c.o
[4/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1a_99.c.o
[5/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1b_1.c.o
[6/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1b_2.c.o
[7/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1b_3.c.o
[8/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1b_4.c.o
[9/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1b_5.c.o
[10/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1b_6.c.o
[11/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1b_7.c.o
[12/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1b_8.c.o
[13/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1b_9.c.o
[14/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1b_99.c.o
[15/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1b_9x.c.o
[16/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1b_cc.c.o
[17/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1b_d1.c.o
[18/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1b_d2.c.o
[19/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1b_rr.c.o
[20/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1b_xx.c.o
[21/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1c_1.c.o
[22/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1c_2.c.o
[23/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1c_3.c.o
[24/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1c_4.c.o
[25/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1c_5.c.o
[26/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1c_6.c.o
[27/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1c_7.c.o
[28/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1c_8.c.o
[29/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1c_9.c.o
[30/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1c_99.c.o
[31/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1c_9x.c.o
[32/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1c_cc.c.o
[33/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1c_d1.c.o
[34/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1c_d2.c.o
[35/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1c_rr.c.o
[36/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1c_xx.c.o
[37/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1f_1.c.o
[38/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1f_9x.c.o
[39/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1f_d1.c.o
[40/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1f_d2.c.o
[41/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1x_1.c.o
[42/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1x_1k.c.o
[43/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1x_1l.c.o
[44/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1x_1o.c.o
[45/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1x_9x.c.o
[46/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1x_d1.c.o
[47/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1x_d2.c.o
[48/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1x_d3.c.o
[49/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1x_o.c.o
[50/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1y_1.c.o
[51/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1y_9x.c.o
[52/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1y_d1.c.o
[53/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1y_d2.c.o
[54/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1y_d3.c.o
[55/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1y_o.c.o
[56/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1z_9x.c.o
[57/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1z_d1.c.o
[58/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1z_d2.c.o
[59/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo1z_d3.c.o
[60/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo2a_9x.c.o
[61/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo2a_d1.c.o
[62/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo2a_d2.c.o
[63/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo_crc.c.o
[64/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo_init.c.o
[65/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo_ptr.c.o
[66/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo_str.c.o
[67/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lzo.dir/lzo/src/lzo_util.c.o
[68/156] Building C object CMakeFiles/lz4.dir/lz4/lib/lz4.c.o
[69/156] Building C object mbedtls/library/CMakeFiles/mbedcrypto.dir/aes.c.o
[70/156] Building C object mbedtls/library/CMakeFiles/mbedcrypto.dir/aesni.c.o
[71/156] Building C object mbedtls/library/CMakeFiles/mbedcrypto.dir/arc4.c.o
[72/156] Building C object mbedtls/library/CMakeFiles/mbedcrypto.dir/aria.c.o
FAILED: C:\Users\Woshi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe  --target=i686-none-linux-android16 --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/Woshi/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/Woshi/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/ndk-bundle/sysroot  -IC:/Users/Woshi/Downloads/nw/ics-openvpn/main/src/main/cpp/mbedtls/include -isystem C:/Users/Woshi/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/i686-linux-android -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -mstackrealign -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -Wall -Wextra -W -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wwrite-strings -Wpointer-arith -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wshadow -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wdocumentation -Wno-documentation-deprecated-sync -Wunreachable-code -O0 -g3 -fPIC -MD -MT mbedtls/library/CMakeFiles/mbedcrypto.dir/aes.c.o -MF mbedtls\library\CMakeFiles\mbedcrypto.dir\aes.c.o.d -o mbedtls/library/CMakeFiles/mbedcrypto.dir/aes.c.o   -c C:\Users\Woshi\Downloads\nw\ics-openvpn\main\src\main\cpp\mbedtls\library\aes.c
C:\Users\Woshi\Downloads\nw\ics-openvpn\main\src\main\cpp\mbedtls\library\aes.c:29:10: fatal error: 'mbedtls/config.h' file not found
#include "mbedtls/config.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
FAILED: C:\Users\Woshi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe  --target=i686-none-linux-android16 --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/Woshi/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/Woshi/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/ndk-bundle/sysroot  -IC:/Users/Woshi/Downloads/nw/ics-openvpn/main/src/main/cpp/mbedtls/include -isystem C:/Users/Woshi/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/i686-linux-android -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -mstackrealign -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -Wall -Wextra -W -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wwrite-strings -Wpointer-arith -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wshadow -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wdocumentation -Wno-documentation-deprecated-sync -Wunreachable-code -O0 -g3 -fPIC -MD -MT mbedtls/library/CMakeFiles/mbedcrypto.dir/aria.c.o -MF mbedtls\library\CMakeFiles\mbedcrypto.dir\aria.c.o.d -o mbedtls/library/CMakeFiles/mbedcrypto.dir/aria.c.o   -c C:\Users\Woshi\Downloads\nw\ics-openvpn\main\src\main\cpp\mbedtls\library\aria.c
C:\Users\Woshi\Downloads\nw\ics-openvpn\main\src\main\cpp\mbedtls\library\aria.c:29:10: fatal error: 'mbedtls/config.h' file not found
#include "mbedtls/config.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
FAILED: C:\Users\Woshi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe  --target=i686-none-linux-android16 --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/Woshi/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/Woshi/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/ndk-bundle/sysroot  -IC:/Users/Woshi/Downloads/nw/ics-openvpn/main/src/main/cpp/mbedtls/include -isystem C:/Users/Woshi/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/i686-linux-android -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -mstackrealign -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -Wall -Wextra -W -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wwrite-strings -Wpointer-arith -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wshadow -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wdocumentation -Wno-documentation-deprecated-sync -Wunreachable-code -O0 -g3 -fPIC -MD -MT mbedtls/library/CMakeFiles/mbedcrypto.dir/arc4.c.o -MF mbedtls\library\CMakeFiles\mbedcrypto.dir\arc4.c.o.d -o mbedtls/library/CMakeFiles/mbedcrypto.dir/arc4.c.o   -c C:\Users\Woshi\Downloads\nw\ics-openvpn\main\src\main\cpp\mbedtls\library\arc4.c
C:\Users\Woshi\Downloads\nw\ics-openvpn\main\src\main\cpp\mbedtls\library\arc4.c:28:10: fatal error: 'mbedtls/config.h' file not found
#include "mbedtls/config.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
FAILED: C:\Users\Woshi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe  --target=i686-none-linux-android16 --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/Woshi/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/Woshi/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/ndk-bundle/sysroot  -IC:/Users/Woshi/Downloads/nw/ics-openvpn/main/src/main/cpp/mbedtls/include -isystem C:/Users/Woshi/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/i686-linux-android -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -mstackrealign -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -Wall -Wextra -W -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wwrite-strings -Wpointer-arith -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wshadow -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wdocumentation -Wno-documentation-deprecated-sync -Wunreachable-code -O0 -g3 -fPIC -MD -MT mbedtls/library/CMakeFiles/mbedcrypto.dir/aesni.c.o -MF mbedtls\library\CMakeFiles\mbedcrypto.dir\aesni.c.o.d -o mbedtls/library/CMakeFiles/mbedcrypto.dir/aesni.c.o   -c C:\Users\Woshi\Downloads\nw\ics-openvpn\main\src\main\cpp\mbedtls\library\aesni.c
C:\Users\Woshi\Downloads\nw\ics-openvpn\main\src\main\cpp\mbedtls\library\aesni.c:28:10: fatal error: 'mbedtls/config.h' file not found
#include "mbedtls/config.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: from the error message `fatal error: 'mbedtls/config.h' file not found
#include "mbedtls/config.h"`, it looks your mbedtls lib dependency is not properly configured.

Comment: it was working fine when it was 3.1.4 and after upgrading to the latest 3.2.1 this error happens